# Using the this pointer inside decltype

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, decltype

**Example** (compiles fine)

```
struct A
{
    void f() {};
    auto g() -> decltype(f())
    {}

};
```

**Question**

If I add the `this` pointer inside decltype (i.e. `decltype(this->f())`), I get the following compile errors with gcc 4.7.0:

```
error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct A'
error: forward declaration of 'struct A'
error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct A'
error: forward declaration of 'struct A'
```

Is using `this` in decltype not allowed? Could someone help me understand what is the problem?

**EDIT**

[This has been filed as a bug](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53721).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems the problem isn't that `this` appears inside a `decltype`, but that it appears **outside the function body.**

For **example**, this code below compiles under GCC 4.7:

```
struct A
{
  int f() { return 0; }
  auto g() -> decltype(f()) {
    decltype(this->f()) var = this->f();
    return var;
  }
};
```

This uses `decltype(this->f())` *inside* the body of `g`, but the specification of the return type of the function in the `auto .... -> ....` form, i.e. the so-called **trailing return type** specification, is **not part of the function body**, and GCC does not allow it there.

**However**, it would appear (see discussion in comments) that the C++ Standard does not actually require `this` to be used in the function body: §5.1.1 of the standard states that `this` may be used anywhere between the optional const/volatile qualifier and the end of the function body, see clause 3 below. (For the sake of completeness, I have added clause 4 as well, which talks about data members and is not directly relevant to the question).

> (Clause 3) If a declaration declares a member function or member function template of a class X, the expression **this**
>   is a prvalue of type “pointer to cv-qualiﬁer-seq X” between the optional cv-qualifer-seq and the end of the
>   function-deﬁnition, member-declarator, or declarator. **It shall not appear before the optional cv-qualiﬁer-seq**
>   and it shall not appear within the declaration of a static member function (although its type and value
>   category are deﬁned within a static member function as they are within a non-static member function). [...]
>
> (Clause 4) Otherwise, if a member-declarator declares a non-static **data member** (9.2) of a class X, the expression this
>   is a prvalue of type “pointer to X” **within the optional brace-or-equal-initializer.** It shall not appear elsewhere
>   in the member-declarator.
>
> (Clause 5) The expression **this** shall not appear in any other context. [...]

NB: The *optional cv-qualifier-seq*, i.e. the `const` or `volatile` qualifier for the function must, as Jesse points out in the comment, appear ***before* the trailing return type declaration.** Hence using `this` in the way described in the question should be correct, and **GCC seems to be wrong.**

Comment: Posting the actual §5.1.1 citation would make this answer complete.

Comment: @ildjarn If you insist... here you go.

Comment: You can also use `std::declval<A>().foo()` if you really want to be explicit, since its parameter can be an incomplete type.

Comment: Thanks this was helpful. However, unless my interpretation is wrong, doesn't the trailing return type come *after* the `cv-qualifier-seq`??

Comment: @Jesse Good You are right. I didn't think of that. GCC may be wrong after all.

Comment: @jogojapan: Okay, if you are in agreement with me, I will look into filing a bug.

Comment: @Jesse Good: I have also looked at some other sections of the standard, but I still think you are right. I have edited the answer in light of this.

Comment: @jogojapan: I filed it as a bug (see link in question). I will accept this as the answer because the provided information led to the answer.

Comment: You haven't addressed the error GCC gives. GCC doesn't forbid to use `this` in that place.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Are you saying that GCC doesn't throw an error, or that the error refers to a different problem?

Comment: @jogo Since I said "You haven't addressed the error GCC gives" I didn't saying that GCC doesn't throw an error. I'm not sure how you come to that conclusion.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb You also said "GCC doesn't forbid to use `this` in that place". One way of interpreting your statement is to assume that if the only problem is the use of `this` outside the function body, then GCC doesn't throw an error (implying that the error described by the OP is due to a different problem). Anyway. What are you trying to tell me? That the GCC error talks about an _incomplete type_ and not about _`this` outside the body_, and I should have addressed that discrepancy?

Comment: Yes. All the text you quoted does not talk about that, while you did *not* quote the text that *does* talk about that. What's more, it's directly following the text in the spec you quoted in clause 3. I'm just surprised that you know the GCC error message talks about something else and you didn't explain how it correlates to the code.

Answer (score 1):

The error message seems pretty clear: 'this' is an instance of 'struct A' which is an incomplete type (that is the compiler hasn't finished parsing the structure during the current pass).

Comment: `decltype` is supposed to allow complete types to some extent (see [N2343](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2343.pdf) vs. [N3276](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3276.pdf)). You're explaining the compiler error, but not asserting that the compiler is correct or incorrect to give that error in the first place.

Comment: If this was the case, using `decltype(f())` to access a member function of the class should result in a compiler error also I think.

Comment: @ildjarn Fair enough - I believe the compiler is correct to give this error.

Comment: The call to a method from within another method of the same class has always to me meant an implied `this` was being dereferenced. I thnk `gcc` must have added some special case code to treat the call differently in `declspec`.

Comment: This has been concluded as a bug in gcc.