# Can we use the decltype of a member function in the parameter list of another member function?

Tags: c++, c++14, decltype, c++17, return-type-deduction

Please consider the following code snippet:

```
template<class Tuple>
class vector
{
public:
    auto size() const noexcept(noexcept(m_elements.size())) {
        return m_elements.size();
    }

    auto operator[](decltype(size()) i)
    {
        throw_if_index_out_of_range(i);
        return m_elements[i];
    }
    auto operator[](decltype(size()) i) const
    {
        throw_if_index_out_of_range(i);
        return m_elements[i];
    }

private:
    void throw_if_index_out_of_range(decltype(size()) i) const
    {
        if (i >= size())
            throw std::length_error("element index out of range");
    }

    Tuple m_elements;
};
```

Unfortunately, [the code above won't compile with clang 3.6 (C++17)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=62d5af42fc2dee2b). It produces the error message *call to non-static member function without an object argument*.

Can we save the idea of the usage of `decltype(size())` or do I need to create some `size_type = decltype(std::declval<Tuple const&>().size())`?

Comment: Why not just use `std::size_t` as it is guaranteed to be large enough to contain the size in bytes of any object.

Comment: @NathanOliver Cause `Tuple` might use some kind of "size" you're not aware of. An "index" might be a complicated object.

Comment: @NathanOliver Moreover, the same question may arise in other scenarios. I'm primary interested in the the technical aspect of the question.

Comment: No problem.  I have never seen a non integer type used as an index but there is nothing stopping anyone from doing so.

Comment: Even if `decltype(size)` were allowed, declaring a typedef would make thing clearer. `using size_type = ..;`

Comment: @NathanOliver There are many things I've never seen, but that doesn't mean that they don't exist ;) That's why I would not use `std::size_t` here.

Comment: @Jarod42 If we declare a typedef we should call it `size_type` in order to stay consistent with the STL.

Comment: @Jarod42 The reason why I would like to avoid defining a (public) typedef is that the size type is the only type we need (it's the question if we really do) to define. All other types can be omitted, if we use auto return type deduction.

Comment: What is stopping you from making it private([see this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eccca1ae9de58cd7))?

Comment: You may use `decltype(std::declval<vector<Tuple>>().size())` if you want to *hide* the implementation (but you show it anyway with auto return type deduction).

Comment: @NathanOliver Nothing is stopping me from doing so. As I said before, I'm primary interested in the technical aspect of the question (and not whether or not this is a good interface design).

Comment: @Jarod42 Sure, that's (almost) how I defined `size_type` in the question. It's a bit lengthy, so I would make a typedef in the case that there is no simple solution of the form `decltype(size())`.

Comment: @NathanOliver You should use `size_type = decltype(std::declval<Tuple const&>().size())` instead, since `Tuple::size` might be qualified. I know, "there is no plausible scenario" where the return type of `Tuple::size() const` and `Tuple::size()` would differ. But since it would be possible, we should stay on the safe side. And we are doing so, if we use the typedef above, cause `m_elements` is const in the context of `vector::size`.

Comment: You can use the same argument in reverse.  since the class contains a non const Tuple then we want to use a non const Tuple in the call to size as the const one could return a different value.

Comment: You can instead say `decltype(m_elements.size())`, if you move the `m_elements` declaration to the top of the class body.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb That would be wrong again. The size type should be the return type of a `size` call on a **const** `Tuple` instance, cause that's the type which `vector::size` actually returns.

Comment: Reviewing the comments, I conclude that there is no better option than declaring `size_type` as suggested in the question (for the moment).

Comment: @0xbadf00d and the type is const size_t then? I don't think so :p You have a point for .begin and .end (for which I don't recommend my workaround), but not about .size() I suspect

Answer (score 0):

There is only a limited scope within which `this` is a valid expression, and in your case it starts [right after you need it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11093653). You can introduce an object (of sorts) to make sure the call to `size` is valid, playing the role of the implicit `this->`:

```
auto operator[](decltype( std::declval<vector&>().size() ) i);
```

That being said, I’d argue against it—and I’d argue against it even if you had access to `this`. The declaration is plainly hard to read and understand, for no benefit at all. Especially consider that you repeat the `decltype( … )` in the `const`-qualified overload as well, with the consequence that a reviewer would have to carefully parse which expression is being tested there and backtrack to the *previous* overload to check what differences, if any, there are in the expressions.

Don’t repeat yourself, refactor:

```
using size_type = …; // choose one spec and stick to it

auto operator[](size_type i);
auto operator[](size_type i) const;
```

`size_type` doesn’t have to be part of the public interface either, we only care about avoiding repetition.